# Passing dates from R chunk to ojs chunk using ojs_define in Quarto

Tags: r, observable, quarto, ojs

I am using R and ojs code chunks in a quarto document where I do data manipulation in R and the pass the data frame to the ojs chunk by using the `ojs_define` function.

My issue is that date seems to be interpreted as string in ojs chunk. The result is bad formatting in plots.

Any tips on how to pass a date from r to ojs in a way that the ojs plot function recognizes it as a date?

Example:

````
---
title: "Code example"
format: html
editor: visual
execute:
  echo: false
  warning: false
---

```{r}
#Some data with a date column
library(tidyverse)

df<-data.frame(day=seq.Date(from=as.Date('2023-01-01'), 
                            to=as.Date('2023-06-15'), 
                            by='days'))%>%
  mutate(values=rnorm(mean= 10, sd=2, n =n()))

#Passing this to ojs through ojs_define

ojs_define(plot_data=df)
```


```{ojs}

Chart = Plot.plot({
  marks: [
    Plot.line(transpose(plot_data), 
      {x: "day", y: "values"}, 
      { stroke: "black" }
    )
  ]}
)
```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since dates are being parsed as string when passed through the `ojs_define`, we can transform back the string-dates type to datetime type in the ojs chunk.

Here we will use [`d3.timeParse`](https://github.com/d3/d3-time-format#timeParse) to create a datetime parser and will use the [`Arquero`](https://observablehq.com/@uwdata/introducing-arquero) library (inspired by the design of `dplyr`) to [`derive`](https://observablehq.com/@uwdata/introducing-arquero#cell-351) (i.e mutate) the `day` column to have datetime values.

Two things to note here,

1. [`Arquero` work with data tables](https://observablehq.com/@uwdata/introducing-arquero#cell-24). But the `plot_data` is of JSON format. So we need to [`transpose`](https://quarto.org/docs/interactive/ojs/data-sources.html#transpose) it to convert it to an array of objects which then passed to [`aq.from` to convert as table](https://observablehq.com/@uwdata/introducing-arquero#cell-64).
2. To use that `parser` within `derive`, we need to wrap `d => parse(d)` with [`aq.escape`](https://observablehq.com/@uwdata/introducing-arquero#cell-1102)

````
---
title: "Code example"
format: html
execute:
  echo: false
  warning: false
---

```{r}
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(day = seq.Date(
        from = as.Date('2023-01-01'),
        to = as.Date('2023-06-15'),
        by = 'days'
      )) %>%
  mutate(
    values = rnorm(mean = 10, sd = 2, n = n())
  )

ojs_define(plot_data=df)
```

```{ojs}
import { aq } from '@uwdata/arquero'
d3 = require("d3@7")
parser = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d");
```

## Plot

```{ojs}
final_data = aq.from(transpose(plot_data))
  .derive({ day: aq.escape(d => parser(d.day)) })
```

```{ojs}
Chart = Plot.plot({
  marks: [
    Plot.line(final_data, 
      {x: "day", y: "values"}, 
      { stroke: "black" }
    )
  ]}
)
```
````

[image: observable plot with datetime axis]